# jquery toggleClass() - access selected element

Tags: jquery

I want to [toggle a class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) based on some condition **which I have to compute from the ID of the processed element**:

```
$(".centre li").toggleClass("highlight", someFunction(x));
```

(This will select about 10 list elements. I need each element's ID to look up if it requires highlighting or not.)

```
someFunction(selectedElement) {
  if (selectedElement.id in someArray)
    return true
  else
    return false
}
```

I might have **lost my way in closure-hell**, but `this` in the function is set to another element. This is the real code:

```
...
showListItem = function(linkSelector, listSelectors, contentSelector) {
return function() {
    $(".centre li").toggleClass("backgroundFullOrange", test(this));
    function test(a) {
        console.log($(a).attr("id")); // -> id of the linkSelector-element
    }
}
};  
$(linkSelector).bind('click', showListItem(linkSelector, listSelectors, contentSelector))
...
```

**Update**: turned out that toggleClass() was not the function I've been looking for. See accepted answer for correct usage.

Comment: Having an `if` statement that **only** returns `true` or `false` is unnecessary. Your `selectedElement.id in someArray` clause will return a boolean value, so simply return that.

Comment: @Anthony - I know. Just thought it's easier to read for you guys. It's pseudo-code after all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `$(".centre li").toggleClass("highlight", someFunction(x));` is not a correct syntax. The 2nd arg is `switch` and the definition is as below,

> switchA boolean value to determine whether the class should be added
>   or removed.

**switch cannot be a function as you have.**

In your case you going to have to call `.removeClass('highlight')` and then `addClass` inside which you can compare the ID of the element and return highlight or ''.

See DEMO which randomly highlights 2 li's every 1.5 secs.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/jTJ2H/6/)

```
    $(".centre li")
       .removeClass('highlight')
       .addClass(function () {
           return ($.inArray(this.id, someArray) >= 0)?'highlight': '';
       });
```

---

I think I understood it correctly this time. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/jTJ2H/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var someArray = ['l1', 'l8'];

    $(".centre li").toggleClass(function() {
        return ($.inArray(this.id, someArray) >= 0)?'highlight':'';
    });

});
```

---

Try using `.filter`. Something like below,

```
$(".centre li").filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.id, someArray);
}).toggleClass("highlight");
```

The highlight will be added only to those elements that are returned by the filter.

Comment: thx for answering, but this doesn't solve my problem, which is getting the id of the selected element for the filter (see updated question)

Comment: @jangroth Inside `.filter` you can access the `id` of the element. `this` will be the current `li`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @jangroth In the function passed to `.filter()` you can use `this` to refer to the current element in the set.

Comment: @jangroth Are you trying to add/remove class based on the ID? Basically trying to control the switch?

Comment: @SKS - I'm adding / removing classes based on the ID which comes from a lookup array. This makes sense, it's static code which looks a bit dynamic, but there is another level of indirection which I added to the question with my last update.

Comment: @jangroth You cannot use `.toggle` as you have. See updated answer.